# How to prevent an update to install on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

There is a recent update to Windows (KB4013429) that is incompatible with an application that we are using.

I would like to prevent this update from installing. How can I achieve this ?

EDIT: The tool suggested in the answer gives shows only five 'hideable' updates out of tens (or even hundreds).

[image: Hide updates tool]

Comment: Just simply hide this update....

Comment: @reborn How are you *hiding* an update ? Do you mean *uninstall* it ? Is this enough to avoid that Windows is installing it again the next time it updates itself ?

Comment: no. since 1607 ( i believe so) microsoft allows to hide updates and they wont be installed. If you have OEM install, then you might not have this option.. In any other case - check Update tab there was 'show/hide updates' link.. (not really  sure about full name)

Comment: I have Windows Professional version 1607, but I cannot find this option.

Comment: Could you find this update and right click on that? There must be such action.. ( sorry, can't tell more accurate atm)

Comment: @reborn In *Parameters - Update & security - Update History* I have a link *Uninstall updates* that leads me to the Control Panel. There I have the option to uninstall the Update. What I really fear (from earlier experiences) is that Windows will reinstall them again.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I answered this just now, you're indeed correct, it'll reinstall. But microsoft provides a downloadable tool to prevent that from happening.

Comment: do a search. This is already answered way ago. I posted in the duplicate topic how to control updates. Also the problematic update is replaced with KB4015438 which fixes the issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can "hide" an update (uninstall and prevent it from being auto installed again) on windows 10.

This functionality does not exist within Windows 10 itself, but you can download a tool from microsoft to do this here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-windows-10

Microsoft also has a nicely put guide on how to use this tool. Once you "hide" an update in this tool, it will not be automatically re-installed.

To uninstall the update on computers that already have it, you need to go to the **settings app**, and then to **"update and security"** and then to **"update history"**. There you'll see a link to **"uninstall updates"**.

Comment: This tool in fact allows to hide only very few updates. In my case, it shows only 5 updates that are 'hideable', while there are tens of updates installed.

Comment: The one I need to hide is not hideable.